# debian 5 VMWare image and keyboard

Tags: installation, debian

I just installed VMWare image for Debian 5.0 and I can not type - so I can not run apt-get.

I am using a Microsoft Natural keyboard.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to ssh to that virtual server and see for the output of 'dmesg' to get some hints what could be wrong with that vm.

If it's virtual USB device support related, why don't use Debian 6.0 with a more recent kernel?

Comment: I upgraded to Debian 6.0, there was no reason to stay with 5.0 and the problem is not there at all